# IMAPIProp::SaveChanges: MAPI_E_NO_ACCESS while trying to run operation on RDOMail Object

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, ms-office, outlook-redemption

I am trying to save some changes to the RDOMail, but I am getting the following exception - 
`Error in IMAPIProp::SaveChanges: MAPI_E_NO_ACCESS\r\nulVersion: 0\r\nComponent: Outlook Data File\r\nulLowLevelError: 0\r\nulContext: 805634561`.

```
_rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = app.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
RDOStore sto = _rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(_Account[0].DeliveryStore, Missing.Value);
RDOFolder folder = sto.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
RDOItems Items = folder.Items;
for (int i = 1; i <= Items.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        RDOMail mail = Items.Item(i);
        if (mail != null)
        {
            mail.Account = (RDOAccount)POP3Account;
            int tag = mail.GetIDsFromNames("{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", "X-Mailer");
            mail.Fields[tag] = _xmailerTag;
            mail.Save();
            mail.Send();
        }
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Comment: How was the message and/or its parent folder opened?

Comment: I have updated the summary with the code

Answer (score 0):

You should never touch messages in the Outbox folder - they are owned by the transport provider from the moment the user clicked the Send button.

If you need to make a modification like that, do it in the `Application.ItemSend` event handler - this is your last chance to touch the outgoing message before it is actually sent.

Comment: is there a way I can debug the smtp communication happening after I hit send with the RDOMail?

Comment: Not really. Firstly, you don't even know if it will be SMTP (it can be Exchange etc.). Secondly, message submission is asynchronous. Redemption simply marks the message as "ready for submission", and the transport provider takes it over at some later point.

Comment: I need to send the emails in the outbox using a secondary account that is POP3Account as mentioned in the code above. But recently I have started having a System.InvalidCastException with message - Specified cast is not valid while casting POP3Account to RDOAccount.
POP3Account is of type RDOPOP3Account

Comment: Where does POP3Account account come from? Are you sure it is really a POP3 account, and not IMAP4 / Exchange / etc.?

Comment: Still, you should never touch the messages in the Outbox folder. If you need to modify a message before it is actually sent, do that in the Application.ItemSend event handler.

Comment: The requirement dictates this scenario. And I am sure it is a POP3 account as I create it during the process of initialization of my outlook addin.

Comment: Then you need to rethink the scenario. Messages in the Outbox folder cannot be touched. Period. Why wouldn't Application.ItemSend event work?

Comment: I am also getting an issue with the RDOPOP3Account, when I try to set the SMTP_Password, or POP3_Password, I am not able to do so. It seems to get overwritten back to the old value. Can you point me in the right direction as what could be the problem?

Comment: You might want to ask a new question and include the relevant snippet of your code.